# Как реализовать верстку (фоновое изображение)?

Tags: background-image

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше реализовать верстку следующего дизайна?

[image: Макет дизайна]

По тз необходимо, чтобы первый экран растягивался на всю высоту вьюпорта, т.е min-height: 100vh;

Из данного макета я могу вытянуть волны в SVG, а также изображение детей с иконками, либо соединить все слои (волны + дети). По макету изображение с детьми должно быть прижато к нижнему краю и держатся в рамках контентной области.

Когда я вставляю волны в виде background-image, У меня возникает проблема при адаптации: при изменение разрешения экрана волны смещаются по высоте.

Показываю наглядно, что получается при ресайзе с волнами:

1. При таком разрешении выглядит хорошо

[image: 1564*800]

2. Но вот что происходит на 1920*1000 и 1920*1200

[image: 1920*1000]

[image: 1920*1200]

Что посоветуете? Из вариантов было вставить как изображение и на абсолютах растянуть изображение, но тогда и контент необходимо размещать абсолютно, что не самый лучший вариант.

И еще мысль была, это убрать для хедера min-height: 100vh и поставить min-height: 800px к примеру, но это уже несоответствие макету.

Буду благодарна за любые мысли и советы)

Comment: а просто background незя ?

Comment: Так при изменении размера экрана например на 1920*1200 выглядит вообще не так, как нужно по макету. Я вот что подумала, может таки сделать на абсолюте под 1900px, а потом адаптировать под 1200px?

Comment: для это существует wrapper - должен быть макет - что и как должно отображаться

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот это:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position-y: 100px;
```

В background-position-y установите желаемый отступ сверху, тогда получится, что фоновая картинка не будет съезжать вниз, а будет растягиваться до конца блока, но с учетом отступа сверху